# how to spawn multiple children, where each child does a different thing?

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, fork

How would you, cleanly, get a parent process to create multiple children, where each child has to do it's own thing. Also the children have to communicate with the parent using unnamed pipes, so I don't think execv can be used here.

I had something like this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pid_t pids[2];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error. Couldn't fork\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) { // child
            if (i == 0) {
                readerChild();
            } else {
                writerChild();
            }
        }
    }

    //parent stuff;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but according to my output, two writer children get created, when I only wanted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that when you `fork()`, both parent and child start up in *identical* states (other than the return value of `fork()`).  So the child will also execute your outer `for` loop, and spawn its own child (see diagram below).  You need to alter your control flow to take account of that.

```
P --> fork --> fork --> wait
           |        --> writerChild -- wait
           |
           --> readerChild --> fork --> wait
                                    --> writerChild --> wait
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening in your code:

The parent forks. i is still 0, so readerChild() is called by that child. The parent AND the child continue to the second iteration of the loop. They BOTH fork again. Thus you get 2 writer children. 1 of them is a child and one is a grandchild.

At the end of your child section, you need to prevent it from looping. put a `break;`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd just write one function per child... unless readerChild()/writerChild() blocks the thread and exits, the readerChild will spawn a new writerChild since it will still be executing within the context of that loop.